# Can a Macro lens be considered useful for shooting other than Macro scenes?

Tags: lens, macro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a macro lens suitable for distant subjects - wildlife, sports, portraiture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14156/is-a-macro-lens-suitable-for-distant-subjects-wildlife-sports-portraiture)

For scenes like Portraits, landscapes, cityscapes, food photography etc, can Macro lens be considered?

Does In some cases it has an added advantage over the normal lens for these scenes?